# Displaying two dimensional array data as a matrix

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some random numbers in a two dimensional matrix. I need to display them on webpage in matrix format, each value fitting into rows and columns. I need to apply DBSCAN algorithm on the values in the matrix for finding the equivalent values nearby. So , iam struck at intial part for choosing display. which is the best way of doing this?? using tables or datatables or any other way... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using a table is the most obvious choice for tabular data, such as a matrix. Your data just should be backed in a variable (or referenced), not just displayed.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the matrix? 
I would write a function in Javascript that produces MathML Code from an given array and process the algo. on this array. Then you can use this function to visualize each step.
To be honst: I have never heared of this Algo.

Take a look at( [MathML Matrixelement](http://zvon.org/xxl/MathML/Output/el_matrix.html) ).